# Can you pass error messages from Service Workers to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, service-worker

I've been trying to work on this for a while. I'm working with google drive api -> and I'm trying to try to get the main script to re-run the request of the accessToken is incorrect and causes an error.

Can that be sent to the main script somehow?

Adding some code to show I've actually worked on this lol - left out some bc it's alot of other unrelated stuff.

I am using IndexedDB to pass info between SW and main Script

```
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////// Check Database onload ///////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

window.addEventListener("load", checkUpload(), false);

function checkUpload() {
  if (supportCheck()) {
    let openRequest = indexedDB.open("GoogleDrive", 1);

    openRequest.onsuccess = (e) => {
      var db = e.target.result;

      var objectStore = db
        .transaction(["backups"], "readwrite")
        .objectStore("backups");
      var request = objectStore.get("1");

      request.onerror = function () {
        // Handle errors!
      };
      request.onsuccess = function (event) {
        var data = event.target.result;
          if (googleSignin.isAuthorizedForGDrive()) {
            // Call SW Function
          }
          else {
            //Google Sign in Error
          }

          let accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;

          data.access = accessToken;

          // Put this updated object back into the database.

          var requestUpdate = objectStore.put(data);

          requestUpdate.onerror = function (event) {
            // Do something with the error
          };
          requestUpdate.onsuccess = function (event) {
            // Success - the data is updated!

            // Call SW Function
          };
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////// Initialize Database Function  ///////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

uploadBtn.addEventListener("click", handleUploadClick, false);
save.addEventListener("click", handleUploadClick, false);

//Adds/Create Data that is stored in IndexedDB so that the Service Worker can 
access and use it
```

//ServiceWorker Call Function

```
function initSW() {
  console.log("Script: Called InitSW()");
  if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register("serviceWorker.js")
      .then((registration) => navigator.serviceWorker.ready)
      .then((registration) => {
        registration.sync.register("sendFile-sync").then(() => {
          //Do Function using sync
          try {
            console.log("Script  : Sync Registered");
          } catch {
            console.log("Script : Sync Not Registered");
          }
        });
      });
  }
}
```

SW

```
  self.addEventListener("sync", (e) => {
  if (e.tag === "sendFile-sync") {
    console.log("SW Sync : Sync Found!");
    e.waitUntil(fetchFile());
  } else {
    console.log("SW Sync : No Sync Found");
  }
});

//Function Called above when sync is fired
function fetchFile() {
  let openRequest = indexedDB.open("GoogleDrive", 1);

  openRequest.onerror = function () {
  };

  openRequest.onsuccess = function () {
    let db = openRequest.result;

    let transaction = db.transaction(["backups"], 'readwrite');
    let backups = transaction.objectStore("backups");

    let request = backups.get("1");

    request.onsuccess = function (event) {
      let date = Date();

      let accessToken = request.result.access;
      console.log("SW Sync: Access Token -  " + accessToken);

      let BlobContent = request.result.text;

      let file = BlobContent;
      let metadata = {
        name: "Backup " + date, // Filename
        mimeType: "application/pdf", // mimeType at Google Drive

        parents: ["root"], // Root Folder ID for testing
      };

      let form = new FormData();
      form.append(
        "metadata",
        new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], { type: "application/json" })
      );
      form.append("file", file);

      fetch(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=id",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: new Headers({ Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken }),
          body: form,
        }
      )
        .then((res) => {
          return res.json();
        })
        .then(function (val) {
          console.log(val.error.message);
                <!-- message is "invalid credentials --> in our scenario
          }
        })
    }


    request.onerror = function () {
      console.log("SW Sync : Getting IndexedDB values error");
    };
  };
}
```

Comment: No idea, you've really [not given folks anywhere near enough details](/help/how-to-ask) to give a meaningful answer...?

Comment: Just added code, just don't know if it helps. I'm trying to get an error message back from the SW if the Google API Access token is incorrect

Comment: To be clear, your use of IndexedDB is **only** to communicate with the SW? Or does it serve an other purpose too?

Comment: also the main "communication" between owner and worker is literally the data return, so instead of throwing, have you considered just _returning_ the `Error` object? There really shouldn't be any communication via indexedDB: for any worker to be well written, it is _entirely independent_ once started.

Comment: @kaiido Yes, we are using the IndexedDB to communicate data with the SW only

Comment: Are you speaking of something like this ?

navigator.serviceWorker.onerror = function (errorevent) {
  console.log(`received error message`);
}

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the ServiceWorker's clients are exposed in its [`self.clients`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients) property, from where you can find the correct [Client](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client) with which you can communicate thanks to its `postMessage()` method.

How to find the correct client will depend on the situation, for instance in the `install` or `activate` events there should be only one client, so you should be able to reach it by doing

```
const clients = await self.clients.matchAll();
const client = clients[0];
client.postMessage("something bad happenned...");
```

In a `fetch` event, the `clientId` is exposed on the event instance, so you can do

```
const client = await self.clients.get(evt.clientId);
client.postMessage("something bad happenned...");
```

I must admit I don't know well the BackgroundSync API, so I'm not sure if in this *sync* event your page would be the only one client, however, you can certainly make your page open a private communication channel with the SW even before, which by the way, sounds like a better mean of passing your API's credentials than through IDB:

```
const channel = new MessageChannel();
channel.port1.onmessage = SWTalksToMe; // handle messages from SW
navigator.serviceWorker
  .register("serviceWorker.js")
  .then((registration) => navigator.serviceWorker.ready)
  .then((registration) => {
    registration.postMessage("", [channel.port2]));
    return registration.sync.register("sendFile-sync")
  })
//...
```

And in your ServiceWorker

```
self.addEventListener("message", evt => {
  if(evt.ports) {
    client_port = evt.ports[0];
  }
});
```

Finally, if you wanted to communicate with all the clients, you could use a [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel).

Comment: Thank you.
I have been learning about the Service Worker/Google Drive Api/ backgrounds sync and IndexedDB all at once. I swear I read the documentation and saw nothing about event ports.

I will look into this more now